# ssh for long running program

Tags: ubuntu, python

I am writing a python script to do things on a remote computer. Actually the python script runs on my computer and the remote computer is a robot running ubuntu.

The command that I am issuing starts the robot software and doesn't exit (except if you kill it with ^c). I would like the command to be issued, be able to display the next 20 seconds of output (or until it goes "quiet") and then have my script actually complete.

I've been trying a combination of subprocess.run (and variants) and ssh options as well as ending the command with an ampersand. None of it works.

Here's what I have so far (you can see some experimental alternatives commented out and in). Everything I've tried either blocks at the ssh (waiting for subprocess to finish which it won't) or just runs through and I don't even see the prompt for the ssh password.

```
def ssh(self, command_line):
        ssh_cmd = ["ssh", "pi@" + self.cfg["BRU_MASTER_IP"], command_line]
        print(ssh_cmd)
        print("1")
        #cmd1 = subprocess.Popen(" ".join(ssh_cmd), shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
        completed_process = subprocess.run(" ".join(ssh_cmd), shell=True, capture_output=True, text=True)
        #completed_process = subprocess.Popen(" ".join(ssh_cmd), shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
        print("2")
        #completed_process.communicate()
        print("2a")
        #cmd1_out = completed_process.stdout.read()
        print(completed_process.stdout.read())
        print("3")
```

Comment: Can you edit your question and paste the code you have written so far?

Comment: An idea. If from a local shell, I would do like `ssh … 'shell code'` where `shell code` is shell code that runs `1>log 2>&1 nohup start_robot_software &`, then `sleep 20`, then `cat log` and then exits (so the local `ssh` exits). I cannot help you in Python, therefore just a comment. Note if `start_robot_software` generates output indefinitely then `log` will grow and grow.

Answer (score 0):

I can assist with Linux/Unix suggestion, weaker at `python`.

Assuming you have an endless long running command:

Lets say `ping $HOSTNAME`

##### And you want to run `ping $HOSTNAME` on a remote machine with ssh:

```
 ssh user@remoteMachine 'ping $HOSTNAME'
```

##### But you want to timeout `ping $HOSTNAME` on a remote machine after 15 secs:

```
 timeout 15 ssh user@remoteMachine 'ping $HOSTNAME'
```

Eventaully after testing that your script is working and respecting the `timeout` command.

##### Finally your Linux command is ready, and your are ready for `python` scripting

Create your `python` script with arguments and parameters to send the above command.

Mind the quotes: `'` has different behavior from `"` (try it out).